# Equating pointers, dereferenced vs normally

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

Below, I have written an example case:

```
struct node{
    int data;
    node* r;
    node* l;
    public:
    node(int val){
        data=val;
        r=NULL;
        l=NULL;
    }
};

node* first = new node(5);
node* prev = new node(10);

first=prev; //case1
*first=*prev; //case2
```

I want to understand, the difference between what would happen in case 1 and case 2.

Comment: this is very basic stuff, hence it would help if you tell us exactly what you are unsure about. Do you know what a pointer is? Do you know what it means to dereference it? Do you know what assignment is?

Comment: You either change the pointer itself, or the `node` it points to. (Perhaps you should reread the last chapter of your C++ book?)

Comment: There is no 'equating' happening here, it's called 'assignment'. For equating use `==`

Comment: A **pointer** holds an **address**.  Just as an **int** holds an integer of some bit-size (32-bit on my platforms).  `pointer p = 0;` and `int i = 0;` are two variables that hold a 0 — 0 address value, and a 0 integer respectively.  (For sake of example, `using pointer = int*;`.)  There's nothing terribly special about a pointer (a raw pointer, that is).  It's just a variable that holds a value (a pointer variable, that holds an address value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assign `first = prev;`, then both of them point to the same node, since they are pointers. But you shouldn't do this, if both of them already were initialized with `new`, since you loose the address of `first` because you overwrite it with `prev`. When they point to the same node, if you change something through `first`, the same is going to happen to `prev`.

In the second case you don't copy the addresses of those pointers but rather their values. So `*first = *prev;` dereferences both of them, therefore they are not pointers anymore but just a node and then assign them, so `first` and `prev` are different objects, with different addreses in memory, but the members of the nodes they are pointing to have the same values.

Lets demonstrate this with a little example (the addresses are made up):

```
node* first = new node(5);      // first = 0x0430; first->data = 5
node* prev = new node(10);      // prev  = 0x03D0; prev->data  = 10

*first = *prev;
// first = 0x0430; first->data = 10
// prev  = 0x03D0; prev->data  = 10

prev->data = 15;
// first = 0x0430; first->data = 10
// prev  = 0x03D0; prev->data  = 15

first = prev;    // causes a memory leak, because we don't know where first was pointing to anymore
// first = 0x03D0; first->data = 15
// prev  = 0x03D0; prev->data  = 15

prev->data = 20;
// first = 0x03D0; first->data = 20
// prev  = 0x03D0; prev->data  = 20
```

You can test this if you just print out the address of each `node*` and the values of them after each case.

In C `NULL` is defined as `((void*)0)`, so it is (casted to) a pointer with the value `0`. The address 0 will always be invalid, you can't store or access data at it. In C++ we have `nullptr` instead of the `NULL` macro, which might still exists but would just be the literal `0`.

And you don't free up the memory allocated with `new` which causes a memory leak. You would do so like this: `delete prev;` so that the operating system can claim that memory we used again. However the line `first = prev;` already leaks memory, because we don't know where first was originally pointing to.

Comment: "so first now holds the same values as prev," no. `*first` is a copy of `*prev` but `first` and `prev` are still different pointers with different values.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Yes, I said "but is still a *different* node". Those have the same values for their members, but the address of them is still different.

Comment: you confuse the pointer and the pointee, which is just what the quesiton is about. "so first now holds the same values as prev" is not correct

Comment: no. `first` and `prev` are the pointers. Pointers do not have members. You mean `*first` and `*prev`, they have the same values in their members

Comment: "(or rather `prev` is just a new name for `first`)" Inaccurate. Even after that line, you could still write `prev = nullptr;` and the value of `first` would be unchanged. They are two separate variables that have the same value, not aliases for each other.

Comment: "By the way NULL is C but if you are using it in C++ it is defined as just 0 and not actually a nullptr and you never delete those nodes." What does this mean?

Comment: @AkshatShahjade I updated my answer, hope it helps a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Pointers point somewhere. In constrast to myths and stories about their magic thats all they do. Pointers aren't magic. Conceptually they are like an index into memory and we can model this via an index into an array:

```
   std::array<double,42> my_memory = {};

   size_t first = 0;
   size_t prev  = 1;

   first = prev;                          // case 1
   my_memory[first] = my_memory[prev];    // case 2
```

`case 1` assigns `first` to `prev`.

`case 2` does not modify `first` nor `prev`. Instead it used `first` and `prev` to reach the elements they "point to" to assign the value at `my_memory[prev]` to the location `my_memory[first]`.

The difference to your two cases is that you do not have a `my_memory` but the pointers just point to places in memory. Rather than using an index into an array, `my_memory[first]`, you dereference the pointer to reach the pointee: `*first`.